# Questions about network protocols

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Are questions about (application level) network protocols ok here?

Comment: In doubth let us know your question, as on meta we can help to find the correct place for it.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on the context. Questions should always be targeted towards solving an actual technical problem you face while administering a system. Remember, our topic is professional system administration, not software development or "Ask an expert" for things you are just curious about.

As an example, if you ask about some details in HTTP to solve an actual problem with your load balancer or something like that, this might be on topic here. If you ask because you want to write your own web server, this would be off-topic.

Comment: Any idea which would be the best suited site if the question is asked by somebody wanting to develop software speaking that protocol?